# Partial derivatives and the chain rule in $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial s^2}$ with $F(s,t)=f(s^2-t^2,ast)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm trying to calculate
$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial s^2}$ for an exercise and I'm a bit confused. The function given is
$F(s,t)=f(s^2-t^2,ast)$.

This is the correction:

$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial s^2} = \frac{\partial }{\partial s}(\frac{\partial }{\partial s}f(s^2-t^2,ast))=\frac{\partial }{\partial s}(2s\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}+at\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2})=2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}+4s^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2}+4ast\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}+a^2t^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2}$

I understand where the first and the last terms come from but not the ones in the middle. The assistant just tells me to use the chain rule and $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ but I feel like I'm missing something very basic and I can't quite put my finger on it.

Could someone please write out a detailed explanation of where each term of the solution comes from, even if it seems obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_1=s^2-t^2$ and $x_2=ast$, then by the chain rule we have $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial s}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial s}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2}$$
$$=2s\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}+at\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2}\space\space (\dagger)$$

and using $(\dagger)$ and the product rule we have $$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial s^2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial s}\big(2s\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}+at\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2}\big)$$
$$=2\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}+2s\frac{\partial }{\partial s}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}+at\frac{\partial }{\partial s}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2}$$
$$=2\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}+2s\big(2s\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}+at\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}\big)+at\big(2s\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2}+at\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2}\big)$$
$$=2\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}+4s^2\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_1^2}+4ast\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}+a^2t^2\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_2^2}$$